# sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y on Ubuntu 18.04 throws error

Tags: ubuntu

I 'm getting the following error below, when I run sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/diesch/testing/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Hit:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease        
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's showing you that for the repository `http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu` your version of Ubuntu (Bionic Beaver) is not available, therefore you cannot use that repo. You either upgrade your Ubuntu version or remove that repository.
If you decide to upgrade, follow [this](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today). If you want to keep your current version and remove the repo, do the following:

1. Locate the line referring to that repository in your `/etc/apt`, run:

```
grep "http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu" /etc/apt  -R
```

2. Use your preferred text editor (vim, nano, subl, gedit, etc) and **REMOVE** that line.
3. Run `sudo apt update` again.

That should do it.

Comment: Also note that [`terminator`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/terminator) is already available in the official repository and has been since at least xenial.  No need for a PPA.  So in addition to removing that ppa from `/etc/apt/sources.list`, consider `apt purge gnome-terminator` and `apt install terminator`

Comment: I took a quick look at that PPA.  The package it supplies was last updated in 2016 (version 0.98).  Since then it has been released in the official archive as `terminator` and is at version 1.91 in bionic.  Doing what I mentioned in the last comment is the "correct" way to upgrade it at this point.